# error: '.class' expected I'm not able to find what is the error. I checked in many websites but not able to find why this error is coming

Tags: java, char

> error: '.class' expected

I'm not able to find what is the error. I checked in many websites but not able to find why this error is coming

```
class Print {
    public static void  printLine(char ch) {
        for(int i=1;i<=40;i++) {
            System.out.print(ch);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        char c='*';
        printLine(char c);
    }
}
```

Comment: `printLine(c);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be a bit more clear about Johnny's correct assessment in the comments, don't specify a type for a parameter in a method call, just in definitions.

So in `main`, `printLine(char c);` should actually be `printLine(c);`